# Access DB autoincrement doesn't let me open the table

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I just managed to connect with a local .accdb Access Database and am now trying to create my tables. I run these two lines with Java and there are no errors during running these SQL-Commands:

```
Statement st = d.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE suppliers ( [name] TEXT(255), [adress] TEXT(255), [ID] AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);");
st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE quality ( [name] TEXT(255) );");
st.close();
```

But now as I want to open the just created tables with Microsoft Access there is a difference between the two generated tables.

I can open the table "quality" normally and insert some values.

Now if I'm trying to open "suppliers" I get this error message:

[image: error message]

It is in German and means "The database '' could not been opened. Either the database doesn't get recognized by your application or the file is damaged."

So I tried to remove the "[ID] AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY" and it works fine without this. So the error must be caused by the "AUTOINCREMENT".

To connect with the database I use ucanacess:

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/bin/Test.accdb");
```

Have I done something wrong with my "AUTOINCREMENT"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your issue with UCanAccess 4.0.2. It appears to be related to the [ID] column being specified last. That is, this causes the issue:

```java
sql = "CREATE TABLE suppliers ( [name] TEXT(255), [adress] TEXT(255), [ID] AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)";
```

... but specifying the columns in this order works okay:

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE suppliers ([ID] AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, [name] TEXT(255), [adress] TEXT(255))";
```

I will pass this information along to the UCanAccess development team.

Comment: Issue fixed in UCanAccess 4.0.3.